# ReferenceError: window is not defined (devToolsExtension)

Tags: reactjs

So, I'm attempting to make 'React Developer Tools' chrome extension aware of my app, but am receiving the above mentioned error. Can anyone advice as to the best way to address this issue?

```html
import configureMiddleware from './configureMiddleware';
import configureReducer from './configureReducer';
import configureStorage from './configureStorage';
import { applyMiddleware, createStore, compose } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, autoRehydrate } from 'redux-persist';

type Options = {
  initialState: Object,
  platformDeps?: Object,
  platformMiddleware?: Array<Function>,
};

const configureStore = (options: Options) => {
  const {
    initialState,
    platformDeps = {},
    platformMiddleware = [],
  } = options;

  const reducer = configureReducer(initialState);

  const middleware = configureMiddleware(
    initialState,
    platformDeps,
    platformMiddleware,
  );

  const enhancers = compose(
    window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
  );

  const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    initialState,
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(...middleware),
      autoRehydrate(),
    ),
    enhancers,
  );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you doing server-side rendering by any chance?

One quick fix I can think of to silence the error when window is not available is to add another check like this:

```
const enhancers = compose(
 (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.devToolsExtension) ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
);
```

Comment: Yes, server-side rendering is being employed. The recommended fix still generates the same error:

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at configureStore (C:/Users/d0475/Documents/Projects/proj/src/common/configureStore.js:30:6)
    at req (C:/Users/d0475/Documents/Projects/proj/src/server/frontend/render.js:42:28)
    at C:/Users/d0475/Documents/Projects/proj/src/server/frontend/render.js:109:19

Comment: Is window being referenced elsewhere in your code? Do you still see this error if you removed the whole line?

Comment: No, window is not being referenced elsewhere. And no, the error does not appear when the line is removed.

Comment: Apologies. I meant to say window is being referenced elsewhere in my general code.

Comment: Your updated answer generates no error, but when 'Redux' is activated within devtools I get the following message, 'No store found. Make sure to follow the instructions.'

Comment: Do you get the message when you remove the line?

Comment: All is working now. The issue with no store being registered in devtools/redux, was due to compose() being defined twice.